# Waiting for transaction confirmation using web3.py?

Tags: python, web3py

I am sending a transaction using:

```
sign_txn = web3.eth.account.signTransaction(token_tx, private_key=private_key)
tx_hash = web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(sign_txn.rawTransaction)
```

and I want to wait for the confirmation of the transaction to continue the work of my script, how can I do this so as not to lose extra time waiting for verification when the transaction is already completed?

Answer (score 0):

I might misunderstand you,

but is `web3.eth.get_transaction_receipt()` what you are looking for?

https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.get_transaction_receipt

if not, please clarify what result you are expecting :)

Comment: I need to pause until the transaction becomes Success or Fail, this function just checks the status of the transaction and if it has not been confirmed yet, it will return an error

Comment: i see!

Maybe https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt works then? 

If not you could create a While loop, where it waits for the receipt to be confirmed.

Comment: This function is also not suitable. I was also thinking about While loop, I wanted to find out if there is a built-in method in web3.py